# Multiple value lookup

Tags: excel, formula, array-formulas

I have been using the following formula for get multiple values from a range, like `vlookup()` multiple values. But when I am editing it to a large range size it is not working. Is there any problem for  this formula with large ranges can any body help
Working formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$13,SMALL(IF(D$2=$A$3:$A$13,ROW($A$3:$A$13)- MIN(ROW($A$3:$A$13))+1,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

My version for a `3000` raw range which is not working

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$3000,SMALL(IF(D$2=$A$3:$A$3000,ROW($A$3:$A$3000)- MIN(ROW($A$3:$A$3000))+1,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try following. Change `D$2=$A$3:$A$3000` to `$A$3:$A$3000=D$2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$3000,SMALL(IF($A$3:$A$3000=D$2,ROW($A$3:$A$3000)- MIN(ROW($A$3:$A$3000))+1,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.